# Check that a text is completely visible in Cypress

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I am using Cypress and I want to check that the user can see a given, very long string.
If e.g. some other element overlaps the text, so that you can only see a part of the text, the test should fail. Also if the element has `overflow: hidden;` and the height is not sufficient etc.
How can I avoid possible false positives from this naive approach?

```js
// passes if the DOM element is visible, even if you see only one line of the text!
cy.contains(someVeryLongText).should('be.visible')
```

Answer (score 4):

The exact approach is likely to vary depending on the CSS of the elements above your long text element.

Here's a minimal page that meets you description. All parents have CSS `overflow: hidden` to suppress expanding the `<textbox>` automatically.

```html
<html style="overflow: hidden;">
  <body style="overflow: hidden;">
    <textbox style="overflow: hidden;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
      Ad repellendus repellat At neque voluptas eos distinctio quos sed quod natus.
      Aut necessitatibus aperiam et ipsam totam sit adipisci recusandae. 
      Ut error dicta non explicabo quia qui fugiat amet.
    </textbox>
  </body>
</html>
```

When this page is displayed in a small viewport of a few hundred pixels, not all the text is visible.

The trick is to compare the element's size to it's viewport.

For example, at 200 x 200 pixels this test passes

```js
it('check for partially hidden text', () => {

  cy.viewport(200, 200)
  cy.visit('/')

  cy.get('textbox')
    .should('be.visible')
    .should($el => {
      const windowInnerHeight = cy.state('window').innerHeight 
      const bounds = $el[0].getBoundingClientRect()
      expect(bounds.bottom).to.be.lessThan(windowInnerHeight)  // text is fully visible
    })
})
```

[image]

Reducing the viewport to 150 pixels overflows the text, and fails the test

[image]